# @RestController in other package doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, maven, package, spring-restcontroller

I start with learning Spring and I create basic project which creates database, insert values and next print it in web browser. 
My problem is that when I have RestController in the same package like main class - its OK, but I want distribute it to other package and when I create new package, move the RestController it doesn't work. Let met explain:

My project looks like:

```
          |-Springtestv_01
            |-src/main/java
              |--com.person <-- it's a main package
                 |-Main.java
                 |-Person.java
                 |-PersonLineRunner.java
                 |-PersonRepository.java
                 |-PersonController.java
              |-com.controller <-- second package, I want put here PersonController.java
            |-src/main/resources
              |-data.sql
            pom.xml
```

My controller looks:

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired PersonRepository personRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/persons")
    Collection<Person> persons(){
        return this.personRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

When everything is in `com.person` package, I write in web brower http://localhost:8080/persons and it works correctly...
But I Want move `PersonController.java` to `com.controller` package, and when I moved it, my webbrowers calls me

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No message
>   available

and I have no idea what I should do to repair it. Maybe I should change something in my `pom.xml` ??

My pom.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.person</groupId>
    <artifactId>person</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringTest_v0_1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId><artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch
            </artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

It is generated automatically, I write only one dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId><artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Please, add spring context.xml

Comment: My guess is you have defined a component scan for the package `com.person` but not for other packages.

Comment: Where I can define a component scan for other pakcage ?

Comment: Are you using spring-boot? Are you using xml configuration or annotation configuration?

Comment: Yes, I'm using spring-boot. My configuration is on `pom.xml`

Comment: Should work with SpringBoot

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Use basePackages:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.person","com.controller"} )
```

Comment: Where write it ? In my `Main.java` ?

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.person","com.controller"})
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}`

I add like U see and it works !! THANKS ! :)

Comment: The variable `basePackages` is needed to something ?

Comment: hi i wanna know why and when should we need to add base packages lik this for what kind of annotation to work with?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem the answers provided here worked for me but i had to add another spring annotation and it's more general in case dealing with a lot of repositories.
We have the following structure :

```
 |-src/main/java
    |--com.person 
       |--repositories
       |--controllers
       |--...
```

This then should be added in th main

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.person"}) 
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.person.repositories")
public class MainDemoApplication { //
}
```

Comment: EnableMongoRepositories: This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Using a `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is equivalent to using `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`.

From the documentation:

> ComponentScan configures component scanning directives for use with
>   @Configuration classes. Provides support parallel with Spring XML's
>   element.
>
> One of basePackageClasses(), basePackages() or its alias value() may
>   be specified to define specific packages to scan. If specific packages
>   are not defined scanning will occur from the package of the class with
>   this annotation.

You can either move it as you did or specify `basePackages` in `@ComponentScan`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the main method is in the package called com.setech.app and a controller is in a package called com.setech.controller.

For spring-boot 1.3.x upwards try this by adding "scanBasePackages" like this.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.setech"} )
public class ResttanslatorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ResttanslatorApplication.class, args);
    }
```

}

Credit goes to Kamil Wozniak from [here](https://smarterco.de/java-spring-boot-mvc-ontroller-not-called/).

Answer (score 4):

We can use `@ComponentScan (basePackages = {"include your package name here"})`.

Also if you have some common package naming format, then we can include just common part of package name with `*` like `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.*"}`, so that all packages having that common package name will get scanned.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but suddenly found that my Application.java class (the class with main method and @SpringBootApplication annotation) located in different but parallel package with @Controller class.

The thing is that Application.java class should be in same or on top of all other packages, then we don't need any @ComponentScan and all beans will be scanned automatically. For example: if Application.java located in com.person and all application beans located in com.person, then it will work without @ComponentScan.

Comment: This is my preferred solution.  In my case I simply moved the Application.java one directory up to automatically scan both controllers from different sub-packages.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using ComponentsScan, we can use @Import.

```
@Configuration

@Import({PersonController.class})

public class MainClassHome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainClassHome.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Maven Case: if you put the controller in another different sub-module(not same as main class), you should add dependency in pom.xml.

Answer (score 2):

Moving the Springbootapplication(application.java) file to another package resolved the issue for me. Keep it separate from the controllers and repositories. You can use any number of packages and have multiple controllers.But use `@ComponenScan(basePackages={" "," "})` and mention all the packages.

Also, you may face this issue `Consider defining a bean of type..` click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384056/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-package-in-your-configuration-spring-boot/)!

Answer (score 1):

You just only define a package name in **@ComponentScan**
like :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.project.pck_name"})
public class MainClassHome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainClassHome.class, args);
    }
}
```

and update project after that:- **right click on Your project -> maven -> update project**

Answer (score 0):

As the one who has struggled with the issue, if you found provided solution didn't work.
Please check whether you put source files at the root level directly, for instance,
`src\main\java\xxx.java`

It has negative effect to project but I don't know the root cause. Anyway,

Please put source files to at least a self-created package like:
`src\main\java\pack1\xxx.java`

Try other settings again. It did solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I find, that if you put the Controller classes in a separate jar, @Componentscan does not find the @RestControllers.
However, @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages =..
does that trick much better.
I used release train springboot spring-cloud-starter-parent, Greenwich.SR4
This resolves to spring boot 2.1.10.Release
So, in this release, @SpringBootApplication <> @Componentscan behaviour on that matter.