# Consider defining a bean of type 'package' in your configuration [Spring-Boot]

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method setApplicant in webService.controller.RequestController required a bean of type 'com.service.applicant.Applicant' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.service.applicant.Applicant' in your configuration.
```

I have never seen this error before but it's odd that the `@Autowire` is not working. Here is the project structure:

Applicant Interface

```
public interface Applicant {
    
    TApplicant findBySSN(String ssn) throws ServletException;
    
    void deleteByssn(String ssn) throws ServletException;
    
    void createApplicant(TApplicant tApplicant) throws ServletException;
    
    void updateApplicant(TApplicant tApplicant) throws ServletException;
    
    List<TApplicant> getAllApplicants() throws ServletException;
}
```

ApplicantImpl

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ApplicantImpl implements Applicant {

private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ApplicantImpl.class);
    
    private TApplicantRepository applicantRepo;

@Override
    public List<TApplicant> getAllApplicants() throws ServletException {
        
        List<TApplicant> applicantList = applicantRepo.findAll();
        
        return applicantList;
    }
}
```

Now I should be able to just Autowire Applicant and be able to access, however in this case it is not working when I call it in my `@RestController:`

```
@RestController
public class RequestController extends LoggingAware {
    
    private Applicant applicant;
    
    @Autowired
    public void setApplicant(Applicant applicant){
        this.applicant = applicant;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloWorld() {
        
        try {
            List<TApplicant> applicantList = applicant.getAllApplicants();
            
            for (TApplicant tApplicant : applicantList){
                System.out.println("Name: "+tApplicant.getIndivName()+" SSN "+tApplicant.getIndSsn());
            }
            
            return "home";
        }
        catch (ServletException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return "error";
    }
    
}
```

------------------------UPDATE 1-----------------------

I added

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("module-service")
public class WebServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(WebServiceApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and the error went away but nothing happened. However when I commented out everything dealing with `Applicant` in the `RestController` prior to adding `@ComponentScan()` I was able to return a string the `UI`, thus meaning my `RestController` was working, now it is being skipped. I got an ugly `Whitelabel Error Page` now.

---------------------UPDATE 2------------------------------

I added the base package of the bean it was complaining about. Error reads:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method setApplicantRepo in com.service.applicant.ApplicantImpl required a bean of type 'com.delivery.service.request.repository.TApplicantRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.delivery.request.request.repository.TApplicantRepository' in your configuration.
```

I added `@ComponentScan`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.delivery.service","com.delivery.request"})
public class WebServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(WebServiceApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

----------------------------Update 3----------------------

adding:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com")
public class WebServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

still is complaining about my `ApplicantImpl` class which `@Autowires` my repo `TApplicantRepository` into it.

Comment: Where is your application context file? If you don't have one, you should consider to give *Spring* some hint with annotations like *@ComponentScan* to make all beans available.

Comment: @MarioSantini please see update 1

Comment: I assume after each update there were changes in the errors? If possible, do post your project structure, and the error logs/stacktrace in each case.. Its better to know "Why" those error occured, rather than a "something" made the error go away. Will be helpful for others who come across a similar issue as well.

Answer (score 347, accepted):

It might be because the project has been broken down into different modules:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.delivery.request"})
@EntityScan("com.delivery.domain")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.delivery.repository")
public class WebServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

Comment: Cool. My project is divided by a number of modules. ComponentScan solved my issue!

Comment: ComponentScan annotation resolve my issue but @EnableAutoConfiguration doesn't

Comment: In fact EnableAutoConfiguration implicitly defines a base “search package” for certain items and using a root package also allows the ComponentScan annotation to be used without needing to specify a basePackage attribute. And @SpringBootApplication annotation could be used if your main class is in the root package

Comment: This solution helped me with this error in version 2.0.4

Comment: Yes, it is due to the fact that the project has been broken down into different modules. `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` with the right package names worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Although IntelliJ says that the ComponentScan declaration is redundant because SpringBootApplication already applies it. Weird...

Comment: yup removing the `@EntityScan` solved the issue, ty

Comment: This works, if you have the file from some other module

Comment: had the same issue when I was trying to run the test classes that out of the main package. after adding the component scan, it worked

Comment: For me @ ComponentScan helped, but had to add multiple other packages for the nested dependencies. Realized later that I had also made use of @ Profile for my class. Ensuring I had added this profile to the VM args for program run solved the issue and I didn't need @ ComponentScan post that.

Comment: For me removal of `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` from `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` works.

Answer (score 183):

**There is a chance...**
You might be missing `@Service`, `@Repository` or `@Component` annotation on your respective implementation classes.

Comment: Yeah this should be the answer. Above answers are simply assuming that the scan failed, which is wrong.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I was going through a few tutorials to create a REST api and they used services to implement the various functions, but not one of them annotated the interface with `@Service` . So here's a solution if someone else has the same problem!

Comment: I forgot to use @Service annotation on my service class.

Comment: I have all these anotations and still the same error, stop copy and paste solutions wothout testing

Comment: @fsalazar_sch Sorry if it hurts ur feelings, I would like to know from where this solution is copied ?
And if it didn't work out for u, plz check another answers in the thread.

Comment: In my case there were 2 beans with the same name, for different objects:

`@Bean
public Foo beanName()
`

and

`@Bean
public SomethingElse beanName()`

Answer (score 66):

Your Applicant class is not scanned it seems. By default all packages starting with the root as the class where you have put `@SpringBootApplication` will be scanned.

suppose your `main` class  "WebServiceApplication" is in "`com.service.something`", then all components that fall under "`com.service.something`" is scanned, and "`com.service.applicant`" will not be scanned.

You can either restructure your packages such that "WebServiceApplication" falls under a root package and all other components becomes part of that root package. Or you can include `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.service.something","com.service.application"})` etc such that "ALL" components are scanned and initialized in the spring container.

**Update based on comment**

If you have multiple modules that are being managed by maven/gradle, all spring needs is the package to scan. You tell spring to scan "com.module1" and you have another module which has its root package name as "com.module2", those components wont be scanned. You can even tell spring to scan **"com"** which will then scan all components in "`com.module1.`" and "`com.module2.`"

Comment: My project is structure is different modules. For example the services will have its own module and `build.gradle`. Those `build.gradle` module names are added to the `dependencies` of the module with the main method. Therefore when you seen `@ComponentScan("module-service")` that's what I thought would work. However inside `module-service` has one package. So my question what would that look like? Do I just name the package name or the module name or somehow both?

Comment: It doesnt matter if the packages fall into different modules. The packages in which the components should be scanned should be specified to spring.  You can give all the "root" package names of all your modules in "scanBasePackages" attribute.. And its all "packages" that has to be mentioned,not modules.

Comment: Did what you said and, the error went away but to only complain about yet another package. Naturally I added it to the list but it will not go away. I implemented it like this: `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"com.delivery.service","com.delivery.request"})`

Comment: I just did `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= "com")` and it is complaining about the JPA repository. Thank you very much. I did not know  spring would scan all packages that start with "com" if you do the above.

Answer (score 32):

Basically this happens when you have your Class Application in "another package". For example:

```
com.server
 - Applicacion.class (<--this class have @ComponentScan)
com.server.config
 - MongoConfig.class 
com.server.repository
 - UserRepository
```

**I solve the problem with this in the Application.class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan ({"com.server", "com.server.config"})
@EnableMongoRepositories ("com.server.repository") // this fix the problem
```

**Another less elegant way is to: put all the configuration classes in the same package.**

Comment: Infact, you do not need to specify `@ComponentScan` in the above scenario. Because your `Application.class` (which has the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation) is placed in `com.server` which is anyway the root for both `com.server.config` as well as `com.server.repository` .

Comment: @Ameen.MThat's my exact question, Why it is still cannot solve and why does it require explicit scan for the mongo repos using `@EnableMongoRepositories` ?

Answer (score 26):

In my case I had a terrible mistake. I put `@Service` up to the service interface.

To fix it, I put `@Service` on the implementation of service file and it worked for me.

Comment: Same for me. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

If a bean is in the same package in which it is @Autowired, then it will never cause such an issue. However, beans are not accessible from different packages by default. 
To **fix this issue** follow these steps :

1. Import following in your main class:
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
2. add annotation over your main class :

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"your.company.domain.package"})
public class SpringExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

## **Important:**

For anybody who was brought here by googling the generic bean error message, but who is actually trying to add a ***feign client*** to their Spring Boot application via the `@FeignClient` annotation on your client interface, none of the above solutions will work for you.

To fix the problem, you need to add the `@EnableFeignClients` annotation to your Application class, like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication
// ... (other pre-existing annotations) ...
@EnableFeignClients // <------- THE IMPORTANT ONE
public class Application {
```

Side note: adding a `@ComponentScan(...)` beneath `@SpringBootApplication` ***is redundant***, and your IDE should flag it as such (IntelliJ IDEA does, at least).

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the issue I was having with the @FeignClient not getting recognized.  But adding the EnableFeignClients solved the problem.  thanks!

Comment: In my case I had to specify the package location in @EnableFeignClients: For example **@EnableFeignClients ("com.myapp.client")**

Answer (score 8):

In my case these two options worked.

1. in `//@ComponentScan ({"myapp", "myapp.resources","myapp.services"})`
   include *also* the package which holds the `Application.class` in the list, or
2. Simply add `@EnableAutoConfiguration`; it automatically recognizes all the spring beans.

Answer (score 6):

This can also happen if you are using Lombok and you add the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` and `@NonNull` for fields but some of your fields are not to be injected in the constructor. This is only one of the possibilities to get the the same error.

> parameter 0 required a bean of type MissingBeanName that could not be found

In my case the error told me what Controller the problem was in, after removing `@NonNull` the application started fine

Comment: This was my error as well except with an `@AllArgsConstructor` removing the annotation and letting java create an empty constructor let spring instantiate the object correctly and inject dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

I faced with familiar problem in my Maven multi-module project with Spring Boot 2. The problem was related to naming of my packages in sub Maven modules.

@SpringBootApplication incapsulate a lots of component like - @ComponentScan, @EnableAutoConfiguration, jpa-repositories, json-serialization and so on. And he places @ComponentScan in com.*******.space package. This part of packages com.*******.space must be common for all modules.

For fixing it:

1. You should rename all module packages. Other words you had to have in all packages in all Maven modules - the same parent part. For example - com.*******.space
2. Also you have to move your entry point to this package - com.*******.space

Answer (score 5):

I think you can make it simplified by annotating your repository with `@Repository`, then it will be enabled automatically by Spring Framework.

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me after adding below annotation in application:

`@ComponentScan({"com.seic.deliveryautomation.mapper"})`

I was getting the below error:

> "parameter 1 of constructor in required a bean of type mapper that could not be found:

Answer (score 4):

Moving the Springbootapplication(application.java) file to another package resolved the issue for me. Keep it separate from the controllers and repositories.

Comment: also mention componentscan(basePackages={" "," "} to consider the packages where your controllers are present

Answer (score 3):

In my case this error appear because my import was wrong, for example, using spring, the import automatically appear:

```
import org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Service;
```

but i needed:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. Mongo DB repository was identified by Spring boot, but it was not creating Bean for a repository interface that extended the mongo repository.

The issue in my case was incorrect version specification in maven pom for "spring + mango". I have changed the artifact's group id and it all worked like magic. no annotations needed as spring boot took care of everything.

During my problem resolution, I was all over web searching for solutions and realized that this problem is actually project configuration related, anyone facing this issue should first check their project setup and enable debug from spring to get more details on failure and pay close attention to where exactly in the process, the creation has failed.

Answer (score 2):

I sought online for an answer but it seems there is no one proper solution to my case: 
At the very beginning, everything works well as follows:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class GroupService {
    private Repository repository;
    private Service service;
}
```

Then I am trying to add a map to cache something and it becomes this:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class GroupService {
    private Repository repository;
    private Service service;
    Map<String, String> testMap;
}
```

Boom!

```
Description:

Parameter 4 of constructor in *.GroupService required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.
```

I removed the `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))` and add `@Autowired` for each `repository` and `service` except the `Map<String, String>`. It just works as before.

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class SecurityGroupService {
    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;
    @Autowired
    private Service service;
    Map<String, String> testMap;
}
```

Hope this might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if the @Service class is marked abstract.

Answer (score 2):

@Configuration annotation will just solve the error

Answer (score 2):

You'll also get this error if you accidentally define the same bean in two different classes.  That happened to me.  The error message was misleading.  When I removed the extra bean, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

My error was that I had included:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

It might help somebody. I had the same problem, same error message, same everything. I tried solutions from other answers, didn't help until I realised that the bean I am using has the same name as the one that is actually been autowired. It happened in the midst of refactor, thus I had to rename the class, which resulted positively. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Try configuring the project structure as given below:

Put all the repo, service, packages in the child package of the main package:

```
package com.leisure.moviemax;  //Parent package
        
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:conf.properties"})
    
public class MoviemaxApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
        
package com.leisure.moviemax.repo; //child package

@Repository
public interface UsrRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity,String> {
```

Answer (score 2):

`@Service` should be imported from `org.springframework.stereotype.Service`

you might be importing it from `org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Service`

In `CrudRepository`, check if the `Entity` class @Id using `import javax.persistence.Id;`, not `import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;`

Answer (score 2):

This error message also pops up when you fail to annotate the Entity classes associated with your bean with the **`@Entity` Annotation**.

My `ComponentScan` worked fine but this popped up for the `@repository` interface:

```
@Repository
public interface ExpenseReportAuditRepository extends 
     PagingAndSortingRepository<ExpenseReportAudit, Integer> {
```

because I failed to add the @Entity annotation to `ExpenseReportAudit`

```
@Entity // <--- Adding this fixed the issue.
public class ExpenseReportAudit {
  .....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan("com.developer.project.mapper")

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a case where i need to inject RestTemplate into a service class. However, the RestTemplate cannot be picked up by the service class. What I did is to create a wrapper class under the same package as main application and mark the wrapper as Component and autowire this component in the service class. Problem solved. hope it also works for you

Comment: This was my case and the proposed solution worked for me. But I didn't understand why Spring cannot find org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

If your class dependency is managing by Spring then this issue may occur if we forgot to add default/empty arg constructor inside our POJO class.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that you are trying to *@autowired* an *interface* before implement the interface.

example solution:

```
    **HomeController.java**
    class HomeController{

      @Autowired
      UserService userService;
    .....
    }
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    **UserService.java** 
    public interface UserService {
        User findByUsername(String username);
    .....
    }
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
     **UserServiceImpl.java**
     @Service
     public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

         public User findByUsername(String username) {
           return userDao.findByUsername(username);
         }
        ....
      }

<i>This is not italic</i>, and [this is not a link](https://example.com)
```

Comment: Please check if you have missed to add Service annotation in your interface implementation class. 
 @Service
public class FsProxyImpl implements FSStatusProxy {

    Override
    public void getFlightInfoWithConnectingGate(List<FlightDetails> flightDetailsList) {
        System.out.println("list val"+flightDetailsList.get(0).getArrivalStation());

    }
}

Answer (score 1):

In my case, our project has a Configuration class, so I just added mine like this

```
@Configuration
public class DependencyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ActivityService activityService(
            @Value("${send.money.ms.activity.url}") final String activityHistoryUrl,
            final HttpRestService httpRestService
    ) {
        return new ActivityServiceImpl(activityHistoryUrl, httpRestService);
    }
```

.......................

Then the microservice started alright.

PS: I encountered this issue even though the library I need is imported properly and could be seen on External Libraries imported.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error, transpired it was an issue with the application properties with incorrect username, password and driver and completely unrelated to Bean.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I also received a similar error:

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'A_REPOSITORY_INTERFACE' in your configuration.
```

Then, according to [Akash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6398838/aakash-k-t)e's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40388609/3815372), I added `@EnableJpaRepositories` to my main class. After that, I received the following error instead:

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

Next, I went through all the responses here, googled a lot and read a lot of other resources, which didn't worked out.

Finally, I was lucky to have found the solution on a blog/website [(javatute.com)](https://javatute.com/). I just followed its examples.

Like suggested by many here, I added `@ComponentScan("YOUR_BASE_PACKAGE.*")` and `@EntityScan("YOUR_BASE_PACKAGE.*")` to my main app class, followed by adding a `config` package and creating a `JpaConfig` class like:

```
package YOUR_BASE_PACKAGE.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "YOUR_BASE_PACKAGE")
public class JpaConfig {

}
```

The blog I followed:

[Consider defining a bean of type in your configuration](https://javatute.com/jpa/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-in-your-configuration/)

which lead me to:

[Error creating bean with name entityManagerFactory defined in class path resource : Invocation of init method failed](https://javatute.com/spring-data-jpa/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory-defined-in-class-path-resource-invocation-of-init-method-failed/)

and finally to:

[Many To Many Mapping In Hibernate/JPA Using Spring Boot And Oracle](https://javatute.com/hibernate/many-to-many-mapping-annotation-example-in-hibernate-jpa-using-spring-boot-and-oracle/)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are missing the @Bean annotation in your RequestController

Add the Bean in your file, this solved my issue 
I got this solution while I was learning Spring Boot from tutorialspoint

```
private Applicant applicant;

@Bean 
public Applicant applicant() { 
    return new Applicant(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding Spring Boot Data JPA Starter dependency solved the issue for me.

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle**

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.2.6.RELEASE'
```

Or you can go directly [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.2.6.RELEASE)

Comment: This actually doesn't apply in this case. It prompts for connection details to database (Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.  ). In a situation where I want to test manually without interacting with the database, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `interface` you can extends `CrudRepository<Applicant,Long>` with `@Repository` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Issue can also appeared when you use per example `@EnableMongoRepositories(YOUR_MONGO_REPOSITORIES_PACKAGE)` and later you renamed the package name or moved it in another place.

Very often faced it within a multi-module maven project and spring boot

Answer (score 0):

**Remove annotation type configuration like @Service from the thread run method.**

```
@Service, @Component
```

Answer (score 0):

reminder that spring doesn't scan the world , it uses targeted scanning wich means everything under the package where springbootapplication is stored.
therefore  this error "Consider defining a bean of type 'package' in your configuration [Spring-Boot]" may appear because you have services interfaces in a different springbootapplication  package .

Answer (score 0):

check the base package name.If the package has different modules that are not prefixed with base package name.

Answer (score 0):

To fix errors like:

- Consider defining a bean of type 'package' in your configuration
- [Not a managed type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28664064/5279996)

It happened to me that the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` class did not have the `setPackagesToScan` method. Then I proceeded to use the `@EntityScan` annotation which doesn't work correctly.

Later I could find the method `setPackagesToScan()` but in another module, so the problem came from the dependency which did not have this method because it was an old version.

This method can be found in the **spring-data-jpa** or **[spring-orm](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm)** dependency of **updated versions**:

From:

```
implementation("org.springframework", "spring-orm", "2.5.1")
```

To:

```
implementation("org.springframework", "spring-orm", "5.2.9.RELEASE")
```

Or to:

```
implementation("org.springframework.data", "spring-data-jpa", "2.3.4.RELEASE")
```

In addition, it was not necessary to add other annotations other than that of
`@SprintBootApplication`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class MoebiusApplication : SpringBootServletInitializer()

@Bean
open fun entityManagerFactory() : LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
    val em = LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean()
    em.dataSource = dataSource()
    em.setPackagesToScan("app.mobius.domain.entity")
    ... 
}
```

GL

[Source](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa)

Answer (score 0):

For me worked a clean install on pom.xml

1. right click on pom.xml
2. expand Run As
3. select Maven build
4. set Goals to the command *clean install*
5. apply > run > close

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse and tried all possibilities and you still have errors, then try to update the project using Maven. You can to this like this: `Right click on your project-> Maven -> Update Project`.

It helped me to solve my errors. Sometimes Eclipse shows this error if a project is not updated with all repos which you declared in the pom file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using MongoDB due to incorrect basePackages name of the @Repository class

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"org.mycompany.repository.mongo.primary"}, mongoTemplateRef = "getMongoTemplatePrimary")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, exact same error message.
But my error only happened when I tried to install and run on my local docker.

Turns out the issue was profile dependant.

I had two classes that implemented the interface, one with a production Profile @Profile("prod")
and the second with the "Test Environment" profiles.
@Profile("!local & !prod")

However, there was no active profile for when I tried to run locally (on Docker).

I created a 3rd class that implemented the interface for a local profile @Profile("local")  and this fixed my issue

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30317663)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have just added `@Component` annotations to some classes (to make sure every Classes have configuration).

`@Component`, `@Service` or `@Repository` are almost familiar. [Baeldung link reference](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this problem was caused by an errant `spring.autoconfigure.exclude` property value. I had this property because my Spring Boot project initially didn't connect to a database, but then I added my first `JpaRepository` class and tried to declare an instance of it with the `@Autowired` annotation in a `@RestController` class.

The line in `application.properties` that caused the problem:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
```

Once I deleted or commented out that line, my Spring Boot service ran just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because of using **@Value** in class that use lombok **@RequiredArgsConstructor** annotation.
Just changed it to constructor injection.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i was get this error for redis repository like this:

```
@Repository
public interface AppTokenRepository extends CrudRepository<AppToken, String> {
}


@RedisHash("APP_TOKEN")
public class AppToken implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String accessToken;
}
```

I solved my issue by adding `@EnableRedisRepositories` over spring boot application class.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by add this config to Application.java file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you have **two beans** with the **same name**.

For example if you have factory method `monkey` creating Monkey and you mistakenly name another factory method (creating Car) also `monkey`.

Problematic code:

```java
    @Bean
    public Car monkey() {
        return new Car();
    }
```

Should be:

```java
    @Bean
    public Car car() {
        return new Car();
    }
```

Reference:

> By default, the bean name will be the same as the method name...

[Spring doc 1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html)

> Autowiring by property name. Spring looks for a bean with the same
> name as the property that needs to be autowired. For example, if a
> bean definition is set to autowire by name and it contains a master
> property (that is, it has a setMaster(..) method), Spring looks for a
> bean definition named master and uses it to set the property.

[Spring doc 2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-autowire)

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Component` for the Class where the Bean is not found.
And Use

> @ComponentScan("<Use_The_Root_Directory_Of_Main_Class>")

.
This can happen when the Components are spread over many directories.

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.example.demo"})
public class Application {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the **"Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'blabla.blabla.blabla.repository' in your configuration."** error and this is how i fixed it;

I was work with a MongoDB. that so, my "EmployeeRepo.java interface" had to contains as like this;

**public interface EmployeeRepo extends MongoRepository<Employee, Long> **

Firstly, the area with the **MongoRepository** part was like this **"JPARepository"**. Then i changed with the MongoRepository. And the problem fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```java
@ComponentScan({"com.delivery.service","com.delivery.request"})
```

File `WebServiceApplication.java` at folder **where the most outter** of all files/packages.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(WebServiceApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was working for me after replacing with jakarta.persistence.Entity instead of javax.persistence and also added `@ComponentScan({"com.myapp.service","com.myapp.repo"})` then solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

For me - using Spring Boot with MongoDB, the following was the Problem:

In my POM.xml I had:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

but I needed the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

(Short: Add "spring-boot-..." instead of only "spring-...")

Answer (score -1):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableHystrix
@EnableHystrixDashboard
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to add something more than a code snippet to your answers, to explain what it is you want to contribute to the topic.