# spring paypal api context issue

Tags: java, spring, paypal

while integrating paypal in spring boot app im getting this issue

```
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field apiContext in com.bookstore.service.impl.PaypalService required a bean of type 'com.paypal.base.rest.APIContext' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.paypal.base.rest.APIContext' in your configuration.
```

my main looks like

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class BookstoreAngularApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
```

the error points to the service where i have used api context of paypal

```
import com.paypal.api.payments.Transaction;
import com.paypal.base.rest.APIContext;
import com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException;
    @Autowired
        private APIContext apiContext;

        public Payment createPayment(
                Double total, 
                String currency, 
                PaypalPaymentMethod method, 
                PaypalPaymentIntent intent, 
                String description, 
                String cancelUrl, 
                String successUrl) throws PayPalRESTException{
            Amount amount = new Amount();
            amount.setCurrency(currency);
            amount.setTotal(total.toString());

            Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
            transaction.setDescription(description);
            transaction.setAmount(amount);

            List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
            transactions.add(transaction);

            Payer payer = new Payer();
            payer.setPaymentMethod(method.toString());

            Payment payment = new Payment();
            payment.setIntent(intent.toString());
            payment.setPayer(payer);
            payment.setTransactions(transactions);
            RedirectUrls redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
            redirectUrls.setCancelUrl(cancelUrl);
            redirectUrls.setReturnUrl(successUrl);
            payment.setRedirectUrls(redirectUrls);

            return payment.create(apiContext);
        }

        public Payment executePayment(String paymentId, String payerId) throws PayPalRESTException{
            Payment payment = new Payment();
            payment.setId(paymentId);
            PaymentExecution paymentExecute = new PaymentExecution();
            paymentExecute.setPayerId(payerId);
            return payment.execute(apiContext, paymentExecute);
        }
```

i have project running the paypal sdk working fine but when i add it to my app im sicking this error of paypal api context

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was cause the name of the package where i putted the config file  must be like base-packages.* i have putted a fast name in the begining I fix it now and make it the package name like others  it s scanned and works fine

Answer (score 1):

I never used `com.paypal.base.rest.APIContext` before but your error message suggests that you need a bean of type `APIContext` so it can be autowired.

> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.paypal.base.rest.APIContext' in
>   your configuration.

Try adding the bean to your configuration class (or xml file if you still using .xml based configuration). Reading `com.paypal.base.rest.APIContext` [documentation](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/blob/master/rest-api-sdk/src/main/java/com/paypal/base/rest/APIContext.java) I would guess that you need something like:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public APIContext apiContext() {
        APIContext apiContext = new APIContext("yourClientID", "yourClientSecret", "yourMode");
        return apiContext;
    }
```

Try this out and see if that works. Keep in mind that `AppConfiguration` must be placed in a sub-package of `BookstoreAngularApplication` so it can be loaded. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907553/field-required-a-bean-of-type-that-could-not-be-found-error-spring-restful-ap).

Later, read `"yourClientID", "yourClientSecret", "yourMode"` from a configuration file instead of hard coding it.

Comment: i ve configured them like that and added keys in Appproperties and called them check my update upstairs pleas

Comment: But what is the error message now? Does it still the same?

Comment: they are in  from the begining @Rafa

Comment: I would guess that spring-boot is not reading `PaypalConfig`. Make sure spring-boot loads `PaypalConfig`, add a `System.out.println("TetingConfig")` and check it is being loaded. Also, try following these steps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907553/field-required-a-bean-of-type-that-could-not-be-found-error-spring-restful-ap

Comment: oh god thank u it was cause the name of the package where i putted the config file he must be like base.* i have putted a fast name in the begining i fix it now and he s scanned thank you @Rafa

Comment: Glad to hear. Please mark as "answered" if that worked for you. Cheers