# 'Field required a bean of type that could not be found.' Spring can't find my repository interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, javabeans

I'm trying to get my skeleton Spring webapp up and running so I can start testing POST requests etc. However, the builder throws an exception:

> Description:
>
> Field repository in
>   com.internal.signing.model.SigningOrder.SigningOrder required a bean
>   of type
>   'com.internal.signing.model.SigningOrder.SigningOrderRepository' that
>   could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.internal.signing.model.SigningOrder.SigningOrderRepository' in
>   your configuration.

I do indeed have a class `com.internal.signing.model.SigningOrder.SigningOrderRepository`. In what context am I supposed to define this bean? My project structure is defined below. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907553/field-required-a-bean-of-type-that-could-not-be-found-error-spring-restful-ap), but the answers do not apply to my case (or so I think).

```
└── com
   └── internal
      └── signing
         ├── Application.java
         ├── controller
         │  └── SigningOrderController.java
         └── model
            └── SigningOrder
               ├── SigningOrder.java
               └── SigningOrderRepository.java
```

My `SigningOrderController.java`:

```
package com.internal.signing.controller;

import com.internal.signing.model.SigningOrder.SigningOrder;
import com.internal.signing.model.SigningOrder.SigningOrderRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SigningOrderController {

    @Autowired
    private SigningOrderRepository repo;

    @PostMapping("/send")
    @ResponseBody
    public String foo()
    {
        Iterable<SigningOrder> orders = repo.findAll();
        return orders.toString();
    }
}
```

My `SigningOrder.java`:

```
package com.internal.signing.model.SigningOrder;

import com.internal.signing.model.Notification;
import com.internal.signing.model.Subject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@Component
@Entity
public class SigningOrder implements Serializable {

    @Autowired
    private SigningOrderRepository repository;

    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private List<Subject> listOfSubjects;
.
    private List<String> authenticationMethods;

    private List<String> signingMethods;

    private List<Notification> listofNotifications;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

My `SigningOrderRepository.java`:

```
package com.internal.signing.model.SigningOrder;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service //This was a tip in an answer with many upvotes in the linked questions. I have tried with
// "@Repository" annotation as well, but to no avail.
public interface SigningOrderRepository extends CrudRepository<SigningOrder, Integer> {

}
```

My `Application.java`:

```
package com.internal.signing;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        System.out.println("In application");
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont inject beans into your entities!

Comment: @mrkernelpanic, could you elaborate?

Comment: Read my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
@Component
@Entity
public class SigningOrder implements Serializable {

    @Autowired
    private SigningOrderRepository repository;

    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private List<Subject> listOfSubjects;

    private List<String> authenticationMethods;

    private List<String> signingMethods;

    private List<Notification> listofNotifications;

        //Getters and setters
    }
```

to

```
@Entity
public class SigningOrder implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private List<Subject> listOfSubjects;

    private List<String> authenticationMethods;

    private List<String> signingMethods;

    private List<Notification> listofNotifications;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

And you need to extend your Spring Config to add following annotations:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.internal.signing.model"})
@EntityScan(value = {"com.internal.signing.model"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        System.out.println("In application");
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not solve the error, but thank you nonetheless. Is there a particular reason why I should separate beans from entities?

Comment: I extended the code example. Please review it again.