# Field in a Service(java file) required a bean of type Repository

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, annotations

I forked a simple spring project from github.
When i Run it, It got the following error

> Description:
>
> Field userRepository in com.example.demo.service.UserService required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.

Comment: Please add some code.

Answer (score 0):

Make the spring boot app aware about the repository location

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={
    "com.example.repository", "com.example.application"})
```

If it doesn't work then follow below thread.

['Field required a bean of type that could not be found.' error spring restful API using mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907553/field-required-a-bean-of-type-that-could-not-be-found-error-spring-restful-ap)