# NoSuchMethodError when using spring-aop 4.2.5 with Spring Boot 1.5.10

Tags: spring-boot

Please help me to solve this issue

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener : org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:413)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:392)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getRunListeners(SpringApplication.java:378)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:291)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at com.ge.pcm.app.PCMApmAlertsServiceApplication.main(PCMApmAlertsServiceApplication.java:53)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils.getSingletonTarget(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:409)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils.getSingletonTarget(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.addApplicationListener(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:105)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.<init>(EventPublishingRunListener.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
        ... 7 more
```

this is my pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>xyz</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <stuf.version>1.5.0</stuf.version>
        <jackson-json.version>2.8.0</jackson-json.version>


        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0.603</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.9</version>

                <configuration>
                    <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPaths}</destFile>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>

            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId> <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>0.7.8</version> <executions> <execution> <goals> <goal>prepare-agent</goal> 
                </goals> </execution> <execution> <id>report</id> <phase>prepare-package</phase> 
                <goals> <goal>report</goal> </goals> </execution> <execution> <id>post-unit-test</id> 
                <phase>test</phase> <goals> <goal>report</goal> </goals> </execution> </executions> 
                </plugin> -->

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Do you have `spring-aop` dependency in your pom?

Comment: Please post your pom.xml, most likely the problem is due to incompatible versions.

Comment: yes i have spring-aop dependency

Comment: Please try increasing your `spring-aop` version to `4.3.16.RELEASE`

Comment: I have updated spring-aop version to 4.3.16.RELEASE but not its is showingDescription:

Field properties in com.xyz.app.xyzapp required a bean of type 'com.xyz.model.Properties' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.xyz.model.Properties' in your configuration.

Comment: Please post the code from these files in the error

Comment: This can help with this new error you are getting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907553/field-required-a-bean-of-type-that-could-not-be-found-error-spring-restful-ap

Answer (score 2):

Increase `spring-aop` version to `4.3.18.RELEASE`. You might need to then make code changes to be compatible with this version.

Comment: Ideally, the `<version>` tag should be removed entirely as Spring Boot manages the version for `spring-aop`. The same applies to a number of other dependencies in the pom including AspectJ and Gson.