# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext Spring Boot + JUnit test

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, junit

I've developed a SpringBoot application with JPA Hibernate and it works pretty well. Now I have to start with tests and I honestly don't know how to solve this error:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:
    Field playersRepository in model.RestService required a bean of type 'model.PlayersRepository' that could not be found.
Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'model.PlayersRepository' in your configuration.

2018-08-23 13:16:51.009 ERROR 7327 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@50f6ac94] to prepare test instance [testing.ApplicationTestSuite@475b7792]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'restService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'playersRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'model.PlayersRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138) ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'model.PlayersRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

I have this class for testing:

```
package testing;

import model.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=RestService.class)
public class ApplicationTestSuite {
@Autowired 
RestService restService;
private static Date start, end;
private static CTF ctf;


@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    start=new Date();
    end= new Date();
    end.UTC(2018, 9, 21, 10, 00, 00);
    ctf= new CTF("CTF test", start, end, null);
}



@Test
public void Ninstance() {

    restService.saveCTF(ctf);
    assertTrue(restService.getCtf().getName() == "CTF test");

}
}
```

I'm trying to test RestService that is:

```
@RestController
public class RestService {

@Autowired
private PlayersRepository playersRepository;
//and other repositories

//methods that use repositories
}
```

My PlayersRepository is:

```
@Repository
public interface PlayersRepository extends CrudRepository<Player, Long> {

List<Player> findAll();
//and other methods
}
```

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907553/field-required-a-bean-of-type-that-could-not-be-found-error-spring-restful-ap) but I didn't find the solution. What should I change or add? Never used this kind of stuff before, please be kind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your test class, you limited the Application context to a specific `Service` class :

```
@SpringBootTest(classes=RestService.class)
```

So your Repository components are not loaded and added in the Spring Container.
To perform an integration test, you could specify as Application context your Spring Boot application class.
No that this is the default behavior as nothing is specified (So just `@SpringBootTest`) and that the package of your unit test class is the same or inside the package of the Spring Boot test class of your application.

Comment: the package of my unit test is `testing`, while all the other classes are under `model` package, so if I remove all and leave only `@SpringBootTest` I get java.lang.NullPointerException. The same if I put my `@SpringBootApplication` class in the classes (`MyApplication.class`)

Comment: sorry you were right, the NullPointerException problem was due to the @BeforeClass setup, but changing the classes into my Spring Boot application class resolved the bean issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For those who searched the error and ended up here, there's other situations that may led to this besides the one that happened with OP. I know of two:

1 - You created a new enviroiment variable in your configuration file. You also must implement it in your test's configuration file, otherwise you will get this error.

2 - You have a exception begin throw inside an constructor or PostConstruct. Track the exception and either fix it's cause or treat it with a try-catch block (a throws won't do) and this error will be fixed.

For example, in the code bellow an API call is made during startup. If a timeout occour outside an try-catch block, an exception will be thrown and the application won't boot, causing the tests to fail. Here I have the fixed code:

```
@PostConstruct
@Scheduled(cron = " 0 0 12 1/1 * ?")
public void updatePaises() {
    log.debug("updatePaises com dados do IBGE");
    try {
        ResponseEntity<List<PaisIBGE>> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(
            API_URL + "/paises",
            HttpMethod.GET,
            null,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {}
        );
        if (exchange.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
            paisIBGERepository.saveAll(Objects.requireNonNull(exchange.getBody()));
        } else {
            log.error("Erro ao atualizar países, código: " + exchange.getStatusCode() + " - " + exchange.getBody());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Ocorreu algum erro inesperado ao atualizar países");
    }
}
```