# Parameter 0 of constructor in *Service required a bean of type '*Repository' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm completely new to Spring. and i have followed this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/)

Currently we are using DB2 on z/OS so i tried to connect to the DB2 using the same way the tutorial used to connect to H2. however after a struggle i successfully installed the Jar files using Maven. but when i try to run this Jar i get this error

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter ٠ of constructor in
>   ess.nbe.dev.essentis.services.Tgen008Service required a bean of type
>   'ess.nbe.dev.essentis.repo.Tgen008Repository' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'ess.nbe.dev.essentis.repo.Tgen008Repository' in your configuration.

And i think the project structure match Spring requirement [disccussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907553/field-required-a-bean-of-type-that-could-not-be-found-error-spring-restful-ap) .

I followed the instructions and i couldn't figure out what is the problem ?

Here's my Code

```
package ess.nbe.dev.essentis.domain;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;


@Entity
public class Tgen008 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String ACT_IDN_SKY;

    @Column
    private String ACT_RFE_NBR_TXT;

    public Tgen008(String ACT_IDN_SKY, String ACT_RFE_NBR_TXT) {
        this.ACT_IDN_SKY = ACT_IDN_SKY;
        this.ACT_RFE_NBR_TXT = ACT_RFE_NBR_TXT;
    }

    public Tgen008() {
    }

    public String getACT_IDN_SKY() {
        return ACT_IDN_SKY;
    }

    public void setACT_IDN_SKY(String ACT_IDN_SKY) {
        this.ACT_IDN_SKY = ACT_IDN_SKY;
    }

    public String getACT_RFE_NBR_TXT() {
        return ACT_RFE_NBR_TXT;
    }

    public void setACT_RFE_NBR_TXT(String ACT_RFE_NBR_TXT) {
        this.ACT_RFE_NBR_TXT = ACT_RFE_NBR_TXT;
    }
}
```

And this is my Repository :

```
package ess.nbe.dev.essentis.repo;

import ess.nbe.dev.essentis.domain.Tgen008;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface Tgen008Repository extends CrudRepository<Tgen008,String> {

}
```

and here's my Service:

```
package ess.nbe.dev.essentis.services;

import ess.nbe.dev.essentis.repo.Tgen008Repository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Tgen008Service {
    private Tgen008Repository tgen008Repository;

    @Autowired
    public Tgen008Service(Tgen008Repository tgen008Repository) {
        this.tgen008Repository = tgen008Repository;
    }

    public long total() { return tgen008Repository.count();}
}
```

and my MainApplication :

```
package ess.nbe.dev.essentis;

import ess.nbe.dev.essentis.repo.Tgen008Repository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.util.Arrays;

@SpringBootApplication
public class EssentisApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(EssentisApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(Tgen008Repository tgen008Repository) {
        return args -> tgen008Repository.count();
    }
}
```

and Application.properties :

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
# Set here configurations for the database connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://ipAddress:port/DBName
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=Qualifier
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=select 1 from tgen008 fetch first row only
# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
```

and my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ess.nbe.dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>essentis</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>essentis</name>
    <description>Program for Essentis DB</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>com.ibm.db2.jcc</id>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
            <version>10.1</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cisuz</artifactId>
            <version>10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2java</artifactId>
            <version>10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc_javax</artifactId>
            <version>10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: `@Autowired
    public Tgen008Service(Tgen008Repository tgen008Repository) {
        this.tgen008Repository = tgen008Repository;
    }` is your problem. Spring can't autowire the `Tgen008Repository`

Comment: Yea im not sure what is the problem with autowiring the Entity automatically , i though @Entity is enough to point to the class

Comment: You use `@Entity` on the actual entity but you don't have any annotation on your interface

Comment: I Though spring do the linking, any suggestions how to link it ?

Comment: you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in?rq=1) Q/A for more info and then decide for yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem, i had 2 jar files `db2jcc.jar` , and `db2jcc4.jar`.

both were in my repository, it seems that the program was using the `db2jcc.jar` instead of `db2jcc4.jar` although i didnt add it in `pom.xml` .

so deleting the `db2jcc.jar` from the local repository solved the problem.

more details about the difference between both Jars can be found in [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21665324)

Answer (score 0):

Change your service in:

```
@Service
public class Tgen008Service {
    @Autowired
    private Tgen008Repository tgen008Repository;

    public long total() { return tgen008Repository.count();}
}
```

Comment: I tried this but i got 
JDBC DatabaseMetaData method not implemented by JDBC driver - upgrade your driver; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Answer (score 0):

```
package ess.nbe.dev.essentis.repo;

import ess.nbe.dev.essentis.domain.Tgen008;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Repository // Need to add this
public interface Tgen008Repository extends CrudRepository<Tgen008, String> {

}
```

Comment: try with @Repository Tag

Comment: Adding an explanation with this code snippet would help improve this answer.