# Spring-boot just doesn't seem to get the repository

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I can't use my CrudRepository in my Service class. I can create the repository, but when I Autowire it to my Service class I get this error:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.test.service.testService required a bean of type 'com.test.repository.TestRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.test.repository.TestRepository' in your configuration.

This seems to be a big issue for many people. I've tried all kinds of things like @ComponentScan, @EnableAutoConfiguration, @EnableJpaRepositories but none of that worked.

Main App:

```
@ComponentScan ({"com.test.repository", "com.test.controller","com.test.service","com.test.model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
    public testService(TestRepository testRepository) {
        this.testRepository= testRepository;
    }
```

Repository

```
package com.test.TestRepository;


import com.test.model.Item;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Long> {
}
```

POM.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I expect the repository to be Autowired and fully functional.

Comment: Please provide your repository code along with the service code. Also please post the stacktrace as well.

Comment: look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057724/parameter-0-of-constructor-in-service-required-a-bean-of-type-repository-tha

Comment: What is the package of your Application class?

Comment: Your repository is place under a package named `com.test.*` whereas you attempt to scan for repositories under `com.test.repository`. Also this needs to be defined in the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation and not within `@ComponentScan`

Comment: this is what I got now:
```@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan (basePackages = {"com.test"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.test"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```
Still no luck

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.test"})
```

Comment: Should have been even better if the define the base packages for the repositories using the basePackages of `@EnableJpaRepositories`.

Comment: You mean like this?

```@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan (basePackages = {"com.test"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}```

Still not working

Comment: Still no luck with

```@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.*")

The error is now somewhat different though:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.test.service.testService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

Comment: that's a different error. It means the repository is found but you don't have an entity manager

Comment: @Andres also again there is no need to define an array for a single value...Just the base package under double quotes would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the @Repository annotation above your TestRepository interface.

> "Spring @Repository annotation is used to indicate that the **class** provides the mechanism for storage, ... " see:https://www.journaldev.com/21460/spring-repository-annotation

Suggestion: Modify your TestRepository interface to extend the JpaRepository. It has more functionality.

Comment: Try this with modifying your package. Your repository is in "package com.test.TestRepository;" but you scan @ComponentScan ({"com.test.repository"...