# Why is bean not found during Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I reconfigured my DAOs to a more convenient way (by using JpaRepository) instead of doing all that boilerplate code manually. But now everytime I start the Spring Application it gives me the following error:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START  
Description:  
Field userRepository in DAO.UserDAOService required a bean of type 'DAO.UserRepository' that could not be found.
    
The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
    
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'DAO.UserRepository' in your configuration.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Annotate your `UserRepository` with `@Repository`

Comment: because it's not a bean. add @Repository to it.

Comment: i read Spring Boot in the title and thought you were actually using Spring Boot

Comment: I use @SpringBootApplication to run my application

Comment: What package is the @SpringBootApplication annotated class in?

Comment: I have added the code of my Application Class above. Take a look at it.

Comment: Repository class needs to be in a *sub package* of “Spring”. Like “Spring.DAO”, not just DAO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLUTION: Just create sub-packages in the same package where you have your Spring appliciation located.

EXAMPLE OF SOLUTION CAN BE FOUND HERE: ['Field required a bean of type that could not be found.' error spring restful API using mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907553/field-required-a-bean-of-type-that-could-not-be-found-error-spring-restful-ap?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You've forgot to put an annotation on your repository class. That's why Spring cannot find that bean.

Try adding `@Repository` on top of your class definition.

Answer (score 1):

Add @Repository annotation then bean will created and autowired in service.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User , Integer>
{
}
```

And don't need to create bean in service

```
@Bean
public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository)
{
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}
```

Comment: I did that and I still get this error:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in DAO.UserDAOService required a bean of type 'DAO.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'DAO.UserRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Removed service @Bean creation in controller also ?

Comment: Yes and still it gives me the same error. It either doesn't find it or there are multiple Bean creations but I already removed the annotations with the corresponding set Methods in the userDAOService and UserController class.

Comment: Are you added org.springframework.boot spring-boot-starter-data-jpa  as dependency ?

Comment: Yes. Just wanted to let you know that I solved the problem. SPring couldn't find the repository because it was in another package. I put the repository as sub-package but some how spring couldn't find service. So I solved it by making sub-packages for models,service,repository and controller and that how Spring could find the repository. But thanks for sticking with me :) .

Comment: You are welcome :) But With Bean creation and without Repository annotation may be it won't work

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that you have your repository class in a sub-package of the `ApplicationConfiguration` class.
2. Annotate the repository class with `@Repository`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, the IDE can often suggests you the wrong import for the annotation of the Bean class, for example for a @Service annoted bean, be sure that you import:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
```

and not something like:

```
import org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Service
```