# Required a bean of type that could not be found REST API

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have already referred [Why is bean not found during Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55064074/why-is-bean-not-found-during-spring-boot) and ['Field required a bean of type that could not be found.' error spring restful API using mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907553/field-required-a-bean-of-type-that-could-not-be-found-error-spring-restful-ap?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
package com.digitalhotelmanagement.digitalhotelmanagement;

@SpringBootApplication
/*
* (scanBasePackages={ "com.digitalhotelmanagement.digitalhotelmanagement",
* "com.digitalhotelmanagement.digitalhotelmanagement.service"})
*/

public class DigitalHotelManagementApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(DigitalHotelManagementApplication.class, args);
   }
```

```
package com.digitalhotelmanagement.digitalhotelmanagement.controller;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("customer")
public class CustomerController {

   private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("ClientController");
   @Autowired
   CustomerService customerService;

   /*
    * getCustomer getCustomerByEmail createCustomer updateCustomer deleteCustomer
    */
   @GetMapping(produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
   public List<CustomerResponseModel> getCustomer(@RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "1") int page,
           @RequestParam(value = "limit", defaultValue = "10") int limit) throws Exception {
       logger.info("Get All Admin List. Pagination parameters: page: " + page + " pageLimit: " + limit);
       List<CustomerResponseModel> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();
       List<CustomerDTO> customers = customerService.getCustomers(page, limit);
       .
       .
       .
       return returnValue;
   }
```

```
package com.digitalhotelmanagement.digitalhotelmanagement.service;

public interface CustomerService {
    CustomerDTO createCustomer(CustomerDTO customer) throws Exception;

    List<CustomerDTO> getCustomers(int page, int limit) throws Exception;
}
```

```
package com.digitalhotelmanagement.digitalhotelmanagement.implementation;

@Service
public abstract class CustomerServiceImplementation implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Override
    public List<CustomerDTO> getCustomers(int page, int limit) throws Exception {

        List<CustomerDTO> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();
        Pageable pageableRequest = PageRequest.of(page, limit);
        Page<CustomerEntity> customerPage = customerRepository.findAll(pageableRequest);

        List<CustomerEntity> customerEntities = customerPage.getContent();

        if (customerEntities.isEmpty())
            throw new Exception(ErrorMessages.PAGE_ERROR.getErrorMessage());
        .
        .
        .
        return returnValue;
    }
```

```
package com.digitalhotelmanagement.digitalhotelmanagement.repository;

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<CustomerEntity, Integer> {

    CustomerEntity findByEmail(String email);
    Optional<CustomerEntity> findById(Integer id);
}
```

```
2020-10-23 22:19:30.710  WARN 25688 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerServiceImplementation'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'com.digitalhotelmanagement.digitalhotelmanagement.service.CustomerService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}


Description:

Field customerService in com.digitalhotelmanagement.digitalhotelmanagement.controller.CustomerController required a bean of type 'com.digitalhotelmanagement.digitalhotelmanagement.service.CustomerService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.digitalhotelmanagement.digitalhotelmanagement.service.CustomerService' in your configuration.
```

CustomerService is just an interface which acts as a middleman between CustomerController and CustomerServiceImplementation, which actually performs operations with the database with the help of CustomerRepository.

I am trying to retrieve data from MYSQL database, i have total of 7 entities, almost having same logics with different functionalities.

Comment: Hi. I think this requires a lot of improvemnt in describing your scenario and what you actually want to achieve. Add some more introduction (self written) to your question. Give some context and describe your concrete problem. Reduce the code snippets to the relevant ones. Write some Info what the code is expected to do and where the provblem in this context is.

Comment: i have edited the post, i uploaded all the necessary classes to get a complete overview of the operations, hope it helps you get a better idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this line:

```
@Service
public abstract class CustomerServiceImplementation implements CustomerService {...}
```

while it should be:

```
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImplementation implements CustomerService {...}
```

You have to `implement CustomerService` in a concrete class, not an **abstract**. Since, abstract classes can't be instantiated.

Comment: I don't even need to look at my program, and realise it is a mistake. Thank you