# Kotlin Field required a bean of type that could not be found error

Tags: spring-boot, maven, kotlin, javabeans

I use KOTLIN / SPRING BOOT(2.5.4) / MAVEN / MARIA DB
I got an error like this, so I thought I have to found make bean.
But I couldn't found What I missed. Can you help me...?

```
> 2021-08-31 13:45:25.923  WARN 7696 --- [  restartedMain]
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'com.example.test0831.repository.UserRepository' available: expected
> at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
> annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> 2021-08-31 13:45:25.925  INFO 7696 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
> 2021-08-31 13:45:25.933  INFO 7696 --- [  restartedMain]
> ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
> 
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
> re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2021-08-31 13:45:25.947
> ERROR 7696 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
> 
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
> ***************************
> 
> Description:
> 
> Field userRepository in com.example.test0831.service.UserServiceImpl
> required a bean of type
> 'com.example.test0831.repository.UserRepository' that could not be
> found.
> 
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>   - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
> 
> 
> Action:
> 
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'com.example.test0831.repository.UserRepository' in your
> configuration.
```

> My Project is
> Kotlin
> com.example.test0831
> └ controller
> └ UserController
> └ entity
> └ User
> └ repository
> └ UserRepository
> └ service
> └ UserService
> └ UserServiceImpl

***package com.example.test0831.controller.UserController***

```
import com.example.test0831.entity.User
import com.example.test0831.service.UserService
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@Controller
class UserController {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var userService: UserService

    @GetMapping("users")
    fun getUserList(): List<User> {
        return userService.getUserList()
    }
}
```

***package com.example.test0831.entity.User***

```
data class User(var id: Int, var name: String, var phone: String, var address: String)
```

***package com.example.test0831.repository.UserRepository***

```
    import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.*
     import com.example.test0831.entity.User
     import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
    
     @Mapper
     @Repository
     interface UserRepository {
    
         @Select("Select * FROM user;")
         fun selectUserList(): List<User>
     }




***package com.example.test0831.service.UserService***
import com.example.test0831.entity.User

interface UserService {
    fun getUserList(): List<User>
}
```

***package com.example.test0831.service.UserServiceImpl***

```
import com.example.test0831.entity.User
import com.example.test0831.repository.UserRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class UserServiceImpl: UserService {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @Override
    override fun getUserList(): List<User> = userRepository.selectUserList()
}
```

***application.properties***

> ```
> spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/userinfo?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
> spring.datasource.username=root
> spring.datasource.password={password}
> spring.jpa.show-sql=true
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should be defining your UserRepository to extend any of the spring JPA [repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html)  interface e.g. `CrudRepository` or `JPARepository`

```
interface UserRepository  : CrudRepository<User, Long> {

     @Select("Select * FROM user;")
     fun selectUserList(): List<User>
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I try to use CrudRepository<User, Long> like your code
but I got same error message... T^T Is my package wrong..?TT I think.. I have to try again..
Description:
Field userRepository in com.example.test0831.service.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.example.test0831.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Comment: Have a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55064074/why-is-bean-not-found-during-spring-boot