# Spring - required a bean of type 'app.user.UserRepository' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring

i just started my basic spring project and encountered some weird problem with beans and autowiring.

**Field repository in app.user.UserModelImpl required a bean of type 'app.user.UserRepository' that could not be found.**

UserModel.java

```
public interface UserModel {

    List<User> findAll();
}
```

UserModelImpl.java

```
@Service
public class UserModelImpl implements UserModel {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        List<User> users = (List<User>) repository.findAll();
        return users;
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserModel userModel;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List findUsers(Model model)
    {
        System.out.println("HERE");
        List<User> users = userModel.findAll();

       return users;
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
@Component
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"app.user"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

All these files are in the same package called user. I'm totally new in this topic so I'm sorry if this is something really basic or trivial.

Comment: Every "class name" (e.g. `UserRepository`) exists in a *NAMESPACE* (i.e. a Java "package").  Q:What packages are "UserModel", "UserModelImpl" and "UserRepository" in? Q: Did you get a clean compile (before the runtime error)?  See this link: [Field required a bean of type that could not be found error spring restful API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43166993/421195)

Comment: I have them all in one package named User, but reordering them into different packages does not help. Also any solutions proposed in this topic does not solve my issue

Comment: The problem is very clear: you've got a class (UserModelImpl) that needs another class (UserRepository) .. but Spring can't find it.  I don't know how much you've "left out" of the code you posted (it looks reasonably "complete" ... but it's obviously not *everything*). SUGGESTIONS: 1) Look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-annotations), particularly the part about `@EnableMongoRepositories`.  2) Create an [MCVE] (with just your app root, simple model interface/impl and your repository) and post it here.  PS: Do you really want your "model" to be a "Service"?