# Pod going in crash back loop

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices

I was trying to deploy my application in one environment. The pod is going in crash back loop with the below error:

> "mdc":{},"timestamp":"2021-06-01
> 09:38:03.582","level":"ERROR","logger":"org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter","message":"\n\n***************************\nAPPLICATION
> FAILED TO START\n***************************\n\nDescription:\n\nField
> bac in
> com.anjana.ms.anjana.ouseph.resources.services.implementation.anjanaValidator
> required a bean of type 'anjana.wrapper.IBAC' that could not be
> found.\n\nThe injection point has the following annotations:\n\t-
> @javax.inject.Inject()\n\n\nAction:\n\nConsider defining a bean of
> type 'anjana.wrapper.IBAC' in your configuration.\n","exception":""}

The application is getting successfully deployed in another environment, Why does it show two different behaviors in different environments, Jenkins build and Junits are running successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Your spring-boot application cannot start successfully that's why kubernetes tries to restart and make it work but fails again..

A `CrashloopBackOff` means that you have a pod starting, crashing, starting again, and then crashing again.

You have a misconfiguration in your application, checkout similar problems like this ['Field required a bean of type that could not be found.' error spring restful API using mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907553/field-required-a-bean-of-type-that-could-not-be-found-error-spring-restful-ap)

Comment: Hi, the JUnits worked fine, Jenkins build is successful, and the pod was successfully deployed in another environment. If this was a code related issue it would have failed in Build stage and in the other environment as well where it worked fine.

Comment: In the error it says `Consider defining a bean of type 'anjana.wrapper.IBAC' in your configuration.` maybe you don't have that configuration in kubernetes? Double check it.