# Get Beans of package

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am writing a spring boot bases application. There are 5 such separate projects and all of the projects share 100+ java files in common and I decided to make a jar out of these common java files.
I have followed below steps to achieve this:

1. Created jar with the common files.(Some are annotated with @Component and some are not)
2. Imported the jar into those 5 applications and used @ComponentScan annotation to scan both the imported jar package and depended project package. This did not work so I have tried installing the jar in local maven repo and adding pom dependency of jar in pom.xml of depended project and still it did not work.

The issue I am facing is even after using the jar in the project, spring boot gives below error:

```
    APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

Field userService in main.java.rest.UsersController required a bean of type 'main.java.service.UserService' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'main.java.service.Something' in your configuration.
```

But I have annotated Something.java with @Component.

I don't understand where am going wrong or if am missing something here. But it works when I write:

```
@Bean
public Something getSomething(){
 return new Something();
}
```

But I cannot write such methods for 100+ components. Is there a way to get all beans scanned with one configuration class or any separate approach to achieve this?

Possible duplicate of ['Field required a bean of type that could not be found.' error spring restful API using mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907553/field-required-a-bean-of-type-that-could-not-be-found-error-spring-restful-ap), but I tried those approaches and still facing same error.

Comment: What does "Imported the jar into those 5 applications" mean exactly?

Comment: It means, if we need that jar in a project, we add the dependency in the pom.xml and the jar is being installed in the local maven repo using the command: mvn install:install-file by providing -D attributes like groupId, artifactId, version and jar location. I do the same thing for all projects. We can also import jar to the project using build path-> add external jar-> choose the jar. I did try these two approaches but still got the same error.