# How to solve issues of required bean in spring boot:?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, maven, configuration

Currently, I'm following a Spring Boot course. However, since yesterday, I'm facing this issue when I launch my main class through VS Code: "Field pr in com.training.training.Service.ProduitServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.training.training.Repos.ProduitRepository' that could not be found." So I'm asking for some help to troubleshoot this problem.

Here is the stacktrace :

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-12-31 14:12:25.347 ERROR 18056 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field pr in com.training.training.Service.ProduitServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.training.training.Repos.ProduitRepository' that could not 
be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.training.training.Repos.ProduitRepository' in your configuration.
```

Here are the features of my project :

- Spring Boot version 2.6.2
- Maven 3.8.3
- JDK 8
- MySQL database version 8.0

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.training</groupId>
    <artifactId>training</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>training</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my code for each class which constitutes my backend side :

TrainingApplication.java (main class) :

```
import com.training.training.Service.ProduitService;

import java.util.Date;

import com.training.training.Entities.Produit;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TrainingApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
@Autowired
ProduitService produitService;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TrainingApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    produitService.saveProduit(new Produit("PC Dell", 2600.0, new Date()));
    produitService.saveProduit(new Produit("PC Asus", 2800.0, new Date()));
    produitService.saveProduit(new Produit("Imprimante Epson", 900.0, new Date()));
}

}
```

ProduitController.java :

```
package com.training.training.Controller;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.training.training.Entities.Produit;
import com.training.training.Service.ProduitService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class ProduitController {

    @Autowired
    ProduitService ps;

    @RequestMapping("/showCreate")
    public String showCreate() {
        return "createProduit";
    }

    @PostMapping("/saveProduit")
    public String saveProduit(@ModelAttribute("Produit") Produit p, @RequestParam("dateCreationProduit") String date,
            ModelMap modelMap) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date dateCreation = sdf.parse(String.valueOf(date));
        p.setDateCreation(dateCreation);

        Produit savedProduit = ps.UpdateProduit(p);
        String msg = "produit enregistré avec Id " + savedProduit.getIdProduit();
        modelMap.addAttribute("msg", msg);
        return "createProduit";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/ListeProduits")
    public String listeProduits(ModelMap modelMap, @RequestParam(name = "page", defaultValue = "0") int page,
            @RequestParam(name = "size", defaultValue = "2") int size) {
        Page<Produit> listeProduits = ps.getAllProduitsParPage(page, size);
        modelMap.addAttribute("produits", listeProduits);
        modelMap.addAttribute("pages", new int[listeProduits.getTotalPages()]);
        modelMap.addAttribute("currentPage", page);
        return "listeProduits";
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/supprimerProduit")
    public String supprimerProduit(@RequestParam("id") Long id, ModelMap modelMap) {
        ps.deleteProduitById(id);
        List<Produit> listeProduits = ps.getAllProduit();
        modelMap.addAttribute("produits", listeProduits);
        return "listeProduits";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/modifierProduit")
    public String modifierProduit(@RequestParam("id") Long id, ModelMap modelMap) {
        Produit p = ps.getProduit(id);
        modelMap.addAttribute("produits", p);
        return "editerProduit";
    }

    @PostMapping("/modifierupdateProduit")
    public String updateProduit(@ModelAttribute("produit") Produit p, ModelMap modelMap, String date)
            throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date d = sdf.parse(String.valueOf(date));
        p.setDateCreation(d);
        ps.UpdateProduit(p);
        List<Produit> listeProduits = ps.getAllProduit();
        modelMap.addAttribute("produits", listeProduits);
        return "listeProduits";
    }
}
```

Produit.java (my unique entity) :

```
package com.training.training.Entities;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Produit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idProduit;
    private String nomProduit;
    private Double prixProduit;
    private Date dateCreation;

    public Produit() {
        super();
    }

    public Produit(String nomProduit, Double prixProduit, Date dateCreation) {
        super();
        this.nomProduit = nomProduit;
        this.prixProduit = prixProduit;
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
    }

    public Long getIdProduit() {
        return idProduit;
    }

    public void setIdProduit(Long idProduit) {
        this.idProduit = idProduit;
    }

    public String getNomProduit() {
        return nomProduit;
    }

    public void setNomProduit(String nomProduit) {
        this.nomProduit = nomProduit;
    }

    public Double getPrixProduit() {
        return prixProduit;
    }

    public void setPrixProduit(Double prixProduit) {
        this.prixProduit = prixProduit;
    }

    public Date getDateCreation() {
        return dateCreation;
    }

    public void setDateCreation(Date dateCreation) {
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Produit [ idProduit = " + idProduit + ", nomProduit = " + nomProduit +
                ", prixProduit = " + prixProduit + ", dateCreation = " + dateCreation + "]";
    }
}
```

ProduitRepository.java (repos for Produit entity) :

```
package com.training.training.Repos;

import com.training.training.Entities.Produit;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ProduitRepository extends JpaRepository<Produit, Long> {

}
```

ProduitService.java

```
package com.training.training.Service;

import java.util.List;

import com.training.training.Entities.Produit;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;

public interface ProduitService {

    public Produit saveProduit(Produit p);

    public Produit UpdateProduit(Produit p);

    void deleteProduit(Produit p);

    void deleteProduitById(Long id);

    Produit getProduit(Long id);

    List<Produit> getAllProduit();

    public Page<Produit> getAllProduitsParPage(int page, int size);

}
```

ProduitServiceImpl.java (the implementation of previous class ProduitService.java) :

```
package com.training.training.Service;

import java.util.List;

import com.training.training.Entities.Produit;
import com.training.training.Repos.ProduitRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ProduitServiceImpl implements ProduitService {

    @Autowired
    ProduitRepository pr;

    @Override
    public Produit saveProduit(Produit p) {
        pr.save(p);
        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public Produit UpdateProduit(Produit p) {
        pr.save(p);
        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteProduit(Produit p) {
        pr.delete(p);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteProduitById(Long id) {
        pr.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Produit getProduit(Long id) {
        Produit p = pr.findById(id).get();
        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Produit> getAllProduit() {
        List<Produit> l = pr.findAll();
        return l;
    }

    public Page<Produit> getAllProduitsParPage(int page, int size) {

        return pr.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size));
    }

}
```

Here are the templates which constitute my frontend side:

createProduit.html (the view for creating Product and store them into DB) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ajouter Produit</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form action="saveProduit" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Nom Produit :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nomProduit" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Prix Produit :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="prixProduit" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">date création :</label>
                    <input type="date" name="dateCreationProduit" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <p th:text="${msg}"></p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="ListeProduits">Liste Produits</a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

listerProduit.java (the view which show a list of all product stored into DB) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Liste des Produits</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Liste des Produits
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nom Produit</th>
                        <th>Prix</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr th:each="p:${produits.content}">
                        <td th:text="${p.idProduit}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${p.nomProduit}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${p.prixProduit}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

editerProduit.html (the view for updating a product initially stored into DB) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Modifier un Produit</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form action="updateProduit" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">ID Produit :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="idProduit" th:value="${produit.idProduit}" readonly class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Nom Produit :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nomProduit" th:value="${produit.nomProduit}" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Prix Produit :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="prixProduit" th:value="${produit.prixProduit}" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label"> Date création :</label>
                    <fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" th:value="${produit.dateCreation}" var="formatDate"/>
                    <input type="date" name="date" th:value="${formatDate}" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Modifier</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="ListeProduits">Liste Produits</a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here my file architecture :

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Best regards,

YT

Comment: Have you moved the main class `TrainingApplication` into its own package? Could you please show how the file structure of your project looks like?

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. package names should be lower case

Comment: BTW: Always add the complete stacktrace. There are a lot of helpful information included

Comment: Also do not longer use `SimpleDateFormat` and `java.util.Date` these classes are outdated since many years. Use classes from`java.time` instead

Comment: @ErvinSzilagy I've updated my post to show you the file structure.

Comment: @Jens I'll try your solutions and I'll give you a feedback

Comment: @Jens, it doesn't work, but I've update my first post to add the the stacktrace

Comment: I think the problem might be, that your `TrainingApplication` class is in a default repository, for some reason Spring Boot is not able to pick up JPA repositories after that. Try adding this annotation `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.training.training.Repos")` bellow `@SpringBootApplication` in the  `TrainingApplication` class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should provide `@Repository` annotation on your class 'ProduitRepository', reference: https://zetcode.com/springboot/jparepository/

Answer (score 0):

I fix it following the instructions given in this forum: ['Field required a bean of type that could not be found.' error spring restful API using mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907553/field-required-a-bean-of-type-that-could-not-be-found-error-spring-restful-ap)

Apparently, I've moved my main class somewhere else. There it cannot scan every component as it did before. However, ty to all of you for helping and answering my question.

Regards,

YT

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You shouldn't create a new answer to thank after replies to your own post.