# Consider defining a bean of type 'com.face.ImageRepository' in your configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Java Spring boot project that I'm creating a post request in. The code looks like this:

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main

{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    SpringApplication.run(Main.class,args);

}

}
```

Java bean:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Image {

private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
private String imageNo;
private String name;

private Image(){}

public Image(String imageNo, String name){
    this.imageNo = imageNo;
    this.name = name;

 }

}
```

Repository:

```
public interface ImageRepository extends CrudRepository<Image, Long> {

 }
```

DatabaseLoader:

```
@Component
public class DatabaseLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

private final ImageRepository repository;

@Autowired
public DatabaseLoader(ImageRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

@Override
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    this.repository.save(new Image("1", "Baggins"));
}
}
```

However when I run the project I get the following error:

```
    Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.face.DatabaseLoader required a bean of type 'com.face.ImageRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.face.ImageRepository' in your configuration.
```

Grateful for any help with this!
Many thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consider defining a bean of type 'package' in your configuration \[Spring-Boot\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384056/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-package-in-your-configuration-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Your spring container will not scan Image repository, since it's not annotated. To fix this you should annotate the ImageRepository with @Repository annotation as below -

```html
@Repository
public interface ImageRepository extends CrudRepository<Image, Long> {

 }
```

Comment: You shouldn't need this if the repository is in the package below the main class. Spring Boot will scan for repository interfaces automatically.