# Azure ServiceBus: 'com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ITopicClient' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, azure, azureservicebus

I am facing the following issue while trying to run the application

> 2021-02-17T18:16:38.159+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Parameter 0 of
> constructor in com.example.demo.service.ServiceBusProducer required a
> bean of type 'com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ITopicClient' that could
> not be found. 2021-02-17T18:16:38.159+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] The
> injection point has the following annotations:
>
> 2021-02-17T18:16:38.159+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] -
> @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> 2021-02-17T18:16:38.159+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Action:
>
> 2021-02-17T18:16:38.159+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Consider defining
> a bean of type 'com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ITopicClient' in your
> configuration.

I have the dependency defined as highlighted below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-servicebus-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and below is the ServiceBusProducer.java class

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ITopicClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.Message;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.time.Instant;

@Log4j2
@Component
@Service
public class ServiceBusProducer implements Ordered {

    @Autowired
    private ITopicClient iTopicClient;

    ServiceBusProducer(ITopicClient iTopicClient) {
        this.iTopicClient = iTopicClient;
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void produce() throws Exception {
        this.iTopicClient.send(new Message("Hello @ " + Instant.now().toString()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

How do I fix this issue? com.example.demo.service.ServiceBusProducer required a bean of type 'com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ITopicClient' that could not be found.

Updated the code however still facing the same problem

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ITopicClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.Message;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.time.Instant;

@Log4j2
@Component
@Service
public class ServiceBusProducer implements Ordered {

   @Autowired
    private ITopicClient iTopicClient;

   ServiceBusProducer(ITopicClient iTopicClient) {
      this.iTopicClient = iTopicClient;
   }

   @PostConstruct
   private void postConstruct() {
      this.iTopicClient = iTopicClient;
   }

   @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
   public void produce() throws Exception {
      this.iTopicClient.send(new Message("Hello @ " + Instant.now().toString()));
   }

   @Override
   public int getOrder() {
      return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Since you did not provide the public default constructor and you added your own non-default constructor the instantiation failed.*

#### Edit:

---

Check out similar issues. It seems you have to initialize `ITopicClient` bean or there has been a naming problem.

- [Consider defining a bean of type 'package' in your configuration [Spring-Boot]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384056/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-package-in-your-configuration-spring-boot)
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19603

Adding naming override might help with this.

Comment: Can you please update the code and help me with the complete class?

Comment: Does this answer help?

Comment: Updated the code however still facing the same problem, can you please refer the question, I have posted the code with recent update

Comment: even I tried making the constructor as public, result is same.

Comment: Pls add an instance instead of parameter: `new TopicClient(.......);`.

Comment: Also, try adding `public ServiceBusProducer() {}` instead.

Comment: public ServiceBusProducer() {} did not work

Comment: not sure what needs to be passed for new TopicClient(.......);

Comment: Sorry, `postConstruct` will remove error but not help in your case because `this.iTopicClient` will not be initialized and is used in other methods. Check my updated response.