# Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.conferencedemo.services.SessionService' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to implement as of enterprise level, there they have folders like **Repository**,**Service**,**ServiceImpl**

1. In Services they have interface with method declaration
2. In ServiceImpl they have class implementing the interface of services
3. In Repository they have all Repository interfaces
4. BeanInjection is a class where we have all repositories and service classes and interfaces with
   **@Autowired** annotation.
5. When I tried to implement "@Autowired" to service class getting this Error.
6. Tried this no help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384056/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-package-in-your-configuration-spring-boot)
7. Tried this no help but getting loop error  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604298/spring-component-versus-bean)

**Controller.java**

```
public class SessionController extends BeanInjectionService {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Session>> list(){
        LOGGER.info("Request received to view the sessions");
        List<Session> sessions = sessionService.findAll();
        LOGGER.info("Successfully fetched all the sessions");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(sessions, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**SessionService.java(Interface)**

```
public interface SessionService {

    List<Session> findAll();
}
```

**SessionServiceImpl.java(Class)**

```
public class SessionServiceImpl  extends BeanInjectionService implements SessionService {

    @Override
    public List<Session> findAll(){
        return sessionRepository.findAll();
    }
```

**BeanInjectionService.java(Class)**

```
public class BeanInjectionService {

    @Autowired
    public SessionRepository sessionRepository;

    **// Error Showing here while starting application
    // Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.conferencedemo.services.SessionService' in your configuration.**
    @Autowired
    public SessionService sessionService;

    @Autowired
    public SpeakerRepository speakerRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SpeakerService speakerService;

}
```

**SessionRepository.java(Interface)**

```
public interface SessionRepository extends JpaRepository<Session,Long> {

}
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Why do you have a common `BeanInjectionService` interface? `SessionServiceImpl` needs an instance of `SessionService` because the parent defines it so -> somewhat cyclic dependency, where the error might occur

Comment: Does your `SessionServiceImpl` have a `@Service` annotation?

Comment: BeanInjectionService is a class where we have all sesionRepository and sessionService variable are defined once and used every where.

Comment: @AbhinavPandey tried it getting circular error

Comment: When i tried removing @autowired to sessionService and running when accessing the route its saying sessionService is **null**

Comment: **ERROR**
   sessionController (field public com.example.conferencedemo.services.SessionService com.example.conferencedemo.services.BeanInjectionService.sessionService)
┌─────┐
|  sessionServiceImpl (field public com.example.conferencedemo.services.SessionService com.example.conferencedemo.services.BeanInjectionService.sessionService)
└─────┘
Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find using `BeanInjectionService` a little weird, but I'll answer around it.

1. Unless you add `@Service` on `SessionServiceImpl`, you can't autowire it.
2. **Circular dependency** - If you do step 1, it will create a circular dependency because `SessionServiceImpl` needs its superclass object(`BeanInjectionService`) to be created first. But `BeanInjectionService` cannot be created unless it finds an object of `SessionServiceImpl`.
3. To break the circular dependency, you have only one option. Don't extend `BeanInjectionService`. Rather, autowire `SessionRepository` directly into `SessionServiceImpl`.

```java
@Service
public class SessionServiceImpl  implements SessionService {

    @Autowired
    private SessionRepository sessionRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Session> findAll(){
        return sessionRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: it's working fine now but the use BeanInjection is avoid redefining the variables at many places right