# Consider defining a bean of type 'packagepath' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I am getting the following error:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in mn.ailab.bankcg.cashout.service.bankservice.BankSelector required a bean of type 'mn.ailab.bankcg.cashout.service.bankservice.CgwBankRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'mn.ailab.bankcg.cashout.service.bankservice.CgwBankRepository' in your configuration.
```

My project structure:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNsYW.png)

I have configured base packages:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mn.ailab", "mn.invescore.ailab"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"mn.ailab", "mn.invescore.ailab"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"mn.ailab", "mn.invescore.ailab"})
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
public class AccountingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccountingApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

CgwBankRepository.java

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
interface CgwBankRepository extends CrudRepository<CgwBank, String> {

    List<CgwBank> findAllBy();
}
```

I have changed base package different ways. But still get same error.

Comment: Is the interface not public?@Repository seems redundant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consider defining a bean of type 'package' in your configuration \[Spring-Boot\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384056/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-package-in-your-configuration-spring-boot)