# spring boot application failed to start. Keeps asking for bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, backend, jdeveloper

Im keep getting this error:
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-08-06T16:52:30.116-04:00 ERROR 36962 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.saferent.saferent.controller.ContactMessageController required a bean of type 'com.saferent.saferent.mapper.ContactMessageMapper' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.saferent.saferent.mapper.ContactMessageMapper' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 0

Applicaiton should run

====MY CODES====

```
package com.saferent.saferent.controller;

import com.saferent.saferent.domain.ContactMessage;
import com.saferent.saferent.dto.ContactMessageDTO;
import com.saferent.saferent.dto.request.ContactMessageRequest;
import com.saferent.saferent.dto.response.SfResponse;
import com.saferent.saferent.mapper.ContactMessageMapper;
import com.saferent.saferent.service.ContactMessageService;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/contactmessage")

public class ContactMessageController {
   recommended. why? has security safety issues.

            
    private final ContactMessageService contactMessageService; //best to do construction injection

    


    private final ContactMessageMapper contactMessageMapper;
    
    @Autowired
    public ContactMessageController(ContactMessageService contactMessageService, ContactMessageMapper contactMessageMapper) {
        this.contactMessageService = contactMessageService;
        this.contactMessageMapper = contactMessageMapper;
    }


    @PostMapping("/visitors")
    public ResponseEntity<SfResponse> createMessage(@Valid @RequestBody ContactMessageRequest contactMessageRequest){
       
        
      ContactMessage contactMessage=
              contactMessageMapper.contactMessageRequestToContactMessage(contactMessageRequest);
      contactMessageService.saveMessage(contactMessage);

      SfResponse response=new SfResponse("ContactMessage successfully created",true);//we can put new here cuz we are creating this once

        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<ContactMessageDTO>>getAllContactMessage(){
      List<ContactMessage>contactMessageList= contactMessageService.getAll();//this will get POJO cuz it gets it directly from DB
        List<ContactMessageDTO>contactMessageDTOList=contactMessageMapper.map(contactMessageList);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(contactMessageDTOList);
    }

   
    @GetMapping("/pages")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<ContactMessageDTO>>getAllContactMesssageWithPage(
            @RequestParam("page") int page,
            @RequestParam("size") int size,
            @RequestParam("sort") String prop,//defines how its sorted
            @RequestParam(value = "direction",
                    required = false,defaultValue = "DESC")Sort.Direction direction) {

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(direction, prop));
        Page<ContactMessage> contactMessagePage = contactMessageService.getAll(pageable);

       Page<ContactMessageDTO>pageDTO= getPageDTO(contactMessagePage);

       return ResponseEntity.ok(pageDTO);
    }
    private Page<ContactMessageDTO>getPageDTO(Page<ContactMessage>contactMessagePage){

        return contactMessagePage.map(
                contactMessage -> contactMessageMapper.contactMessageToDTO(contactMessage));
    }

}
```

```
package com.saferent.saferent.domain;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Email;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_cmessage")
public class ContactMessage {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;//we use Long so we can get null not a number if nothing is giver

    @Size(min = 1,max = 50,message = "Your name '${validatedValue}' must be between {min} and {max} chars long")
    @NotNull(message = "please provide your name")
    @Column(length = 50,nullable = false)

    private String name;


    @Size(min = 5,max = 50,message = "Your subject '${validatedValue}' must be between {min} and {max} chars long")
    @NotNull(message = "please provide your subject")
    @Column(length = 50,nullable = false)

    private String subject;


    @Size(min = 20,max = 200,message = "Your body '${validatedValue}' must be between {min} and {max} chars long")
    @NotNull(message = "please provide your body")
    @Column(length = 200,nullable = false)
    private String body;

    @Email(message = "Provide valid email")
    @Column(length = 50,nullable = false)
    private String email;




}
```

```
package com.saferent.saferent.mapper;

import com.saferent.saferent.domain.ContactMessage;
import com.saferent.saferent.dto.ContactMessageDTO;
import com.saferent.saferent.dto.request.ContactMessageRequest;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
@Component
public interface ContactMessageMapper {
   

   

    
    ContactMessageDTO contactMessageToDTO(ContactMessage contactMessage);
     contactMessageToDTO(ContactMessage contactMessage); we do not need to fill it in cuz it gets it from the dependencies we have.

    
    @Mapping(target = "id",ignore = true)//Ignoring id in request class when mapping.
   
    ContactMessage contactMessageRequestToContactMessage(ContactMessageRequest contactMessageRequest);

    List<ContactMessageDTO>map(List<ContactMessage> contactMessageList);//getAllContactMessage()
}
```

```
package com.saferent.saferent;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication

public class SaferentApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SaferentApplication.class, args);
    }


}
```

===== pom.xml =====

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.saferent</groupId>
    <artifactId>saferent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>saferent</name>
    <description>Car Rental Backend Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version></version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok-mapstruct-binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post and share the relevant code. --- From the looks of it, no bean of type `com.saferent.saferent.mapper.ContactMessageMappe` is discovered.

Comment: Are you using mapstruct? Then you need to add a componentModel argument to the Mapper annotation.

Comment: @Turing85 I have updated my codes you can check it out now. 

yes I am using mapStruct, you can check my pom.xml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consider defining a bean of type 'package' in your configuration \[Spring-Boot\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384056/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-package-in-your-configuration-spring-boot)

Comment: @vaibhavsahu i used and tried all nothing seems to be working

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Community i have trimmed it down. thanks

Comment: @Turing85 I have made the changes nothing. Would you like to see more of my codes?