# sping boot - how to configure application class in a different package, and controllers and services in other package

Tags: spring-boot

We generally define our main application class in a root package above other
classes.

The **Spring Boot Application** annotation in the main application class implicitly loads other classes as its the base package.

MY Question
my main class is in com.example.main
my controller class package is com.example.controller

when i run as Spring boot app, application is loaded but the rest API throws 404, how to configure parallel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@RestController in other package doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039774/restcontroller-in-other-package-doesnt-work)

Comment: Just add `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example","com.example.controller"} )` where you're having `@SpringBootApplication`

Comment: Thank you @Madhu Bhat, I have interfaces for Spring JPA, had to include @EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository") to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your main class is not in root package, you need to annotate `@componentScan` in your main class as below.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.example.controller"})
public class SpringBootApplication {
//...your code.
}
```

In case you want to scan all the sub-class you need to pass the root package path in componentScan

```
 @ComponentScan({"com.example"})
```

Comment: Where can i find the list of annotations related to Spring