# @restcontroller not accepting any mapping if placed in different package, but accepts if placed in main class package

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

I'm seeting up Rest end point & @Restcontroller doesnt accept/Map any incomming requests if placed in difefrent package,but works fine if placed in main class package

Spring boot being set-up in Eclipse IDE.

```
SpringApp.java (main method) in com.java package      --------- Work's fine


@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class SpringApp
{


       @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    String welcome() {
        return "Hello!! welcome";
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringApp.class, args);


    }

}



TestController.java in com.controller package    ----  Doesn't work

@RestController
public class TestController {


    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    String welcome() {
        return "Hello!! welcome";
    }
```

I expected the request to get mapped irrespective of the package in which they are placed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@RestController in other package doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039774/restcontroller-in-other-package-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place it in a package under the package where the main class is

in your case the package name is com.java.controller

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify packages to be scanned while starting application
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.controller"})

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate with [@RestController in other package doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039774/restcontroller-in-other-package-doesnt-work)